# JAXB Tag Wrapping

Tags: java, jaxb

Lets say I have a Java class as follows

```
public class Foo {

   public ... getKitchen(){}

   public ... getRoom(){}

   public ... getInnerPart(){}

   public ... getUpperPart(){}

   public ... getBasement(){}

   ...
   ...
}
```

and I want XML output like this

```
<foo>
   <house>
     <kitchen>value<kitchen>
     <basement>value<basement>
     <room>value<room>
   <house>
   <innerPart>value<innerPart>
   <upperPart>value<upperPart>
<foo>
```

What would the JAXB annotations look like on my class?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the **[EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)** lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

You can use MOXy's `@XmlPath` extension to achieve this mapping:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(propOrder={"kitchen", "basement", "room", "innerPart", "upperPart"})
public class Foo {

   @XmlPath("house/kitchen/text()")
   public ... getKitchen(){}

   @XmlPath("house/room/text()")
   public ... getRoom(){}

   public ... getInnerPart(){}

   public ... getUpperPart(){}

   @XmlPath("house/basement/text()")
   public ... getBasement(){}

   ...
   ...
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Is there anyway to do it with just JAXB JSR-222 provided by the JRE 7? I will have a hard time getting MOXy into the internal network and most of our classes have been using JaxB mainly, it's hard to switch now. Thanks.

Comment: There are a couple of different strategies you could use.  You could map the document to something close, and use an stylesheet to transform to the desired result.  JAXB works well with XSLT by providing `JAXBSource` and `JAXBResult` that work with the javax.xml.transform APIs.  You could also play around with using JAXB with StAX.  For example on an Unmarshal you could use a StreamFiler to eliminate the `house` element.  MOXy is a compliant JAXB (JSR-222) implementation.  You can enable for individual models using jaxb.properties.